# MySQL varchar defaulting to 0 rather than empty string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, varchar

I have a `VARCHAR(45)` field in `MySQL 5.5.24` which is defaulting to `0` when I try and set it to `''`.

I've, somehow, never seen this happen before, or never noticed it.

Am I missing something obvious or is this the expected behaviour?

`ALTER TABLE test CHANGE COLUMN my_varchar_field my_varchar_field VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';`

`UPDATE test SET my_varchar_field = '' WHERE my_id = 1;`

`SELECT my_varchar_field FROM test;`

```
 +-----------------------------+
 |      my_varchar_field       |
 +-----------------------------+
 | 0                           |
 +-----------------------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

`UPDATE test SET my_varchar_field = NULL WHERE my_id = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `test ` CHANGE `my_varchar_field` `my_varchar_field` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

thanks

Comment: Still the same as before doing that unfortunately.

Comment: Then you run this mysql query - you set default value is "". After that please try UPDATE test SET my_varchar_field = NULL WHERE my_id = 1